# Are datasheets translated into other languages (e.g., Japanese, Chinese)?

Tags: datasheet

A recent video I saw surveyed Japanese folk on the street and their knowledge of English. The majority of those surveyed had little to zero working knowledge of the language. So that got me thinking - how do engineers/designers in non-English speaking countries design electronics? From my basic research, I can't seem to find translated versions of datasheets for very common components (LM7805, LM340, etc.).

For example, on the Ti's Japanese site for the LM340 (http://www.tij.co.jp/product/jp/LM340/samplebuy), even the datasheet is in English.

Do companies provide datasheet translations for their parts? Or do engineers in non-English speaking countries time translating the information for themselves?

Would love to get some insight on this. Help satisfy my curiosity!

Comment: You must be looking at a different data sheet from me.

Comment: Is yours in Japanese? The datasheet link on the TI page that I posted is http://www.ti.com/jp/lit/gpn/lm340, which leads to an English document for me.

Comment: Different web address: tij.co.jp, not ti.com

Comment: @Chu For me, the link to the datasheet on the tij site leads to the ti.com address.

Comment: The link in the OP gives Japanese data sheet. Perhaps it depends on location - I'm in UK

Comment: @Chu Can you then post the actual link which you were given?

Comment: I simply clicked on the link in the OP.

Comment: @Chu I'm asking for the link, since what you describe is not happening for me or the OP. So do you have the link or not?

Comment: All too often the datasheet starts out in Japanese or Chinese, then gets badly translated to English.  We call that Jinglish or Chinglish.  Those datasheets tend to be pretty bad, and often leave out important information.  The usual solution is to use a part from a company with a readable datasheet.  Perhaps that's what goes on in Japan and China too?  They use a lot of home-grown parts?

Comment: here's the link that works on my PC: http://www.tij.co.jp/product/jp/LM340/samplebuy

Comment: @Olin While I've seen several datasheets for 'cheap' components (e.g., motors) with awful translations, graphics, etc., I don't see this happening with larger manufacturers (TI, Microchip, etc.). Maybe those start in English? The verbiage tends to be very good and natural. I wonder if the 'big guy' provide translations for all their devices for different languages... seems like a huge undertaking for all the different languages out there.

Comment: @Qua: Obviously the datasheets from Microchip and TI start in English.  I don't know how good their translations to other languages are.  Most large multi-national companies do a decent job.  However, there are many more niche Chinese companies in particular that just don't seem to care about the international market.  Those datasheet, if you can find them at all, tend to be terrible.